# .net core 3.0 worker service to handle http request

Tags: .net, .net-core-3.0

In .net 3.5 framework i used windows service to run multiple thread for each business activity like queue listening, email,sms,db save etc. and control all the threads using nanacyfx in a webportal via http request and it was working fine. similarly i want to use in .net core 3.0 using worker service , but i don't have option to use nancyfx or similar inbuilt web server to handle http requests.

I need windows service so using worker service.

kindly suggest an option for my need in .net core 3.

Comment: Have you read [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)? NancyFX is a framework, not a web server. ASP.NET Core comes with [a built-in web server (Kestrel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Comment: [Nancy 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy/) works with .NET Core. [This sample from the repo](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Kestrel) shows how to combine Kestrel and Nancy

Comment: I already explained that Nancy is a framework, not a server, and a link to samples in the Nancy repo that show how to use it in .NET Core. Did you check the sample?

Comment: ok let me try the latest version nancy. thanks

Comment: I tried using Nancy 2.0 , but it has dependency on framework 4.5 and i can't use it for .net core alone platform. so need a solution in pure .net core 3.0 using worker service.

Comment: I posted a link to a .NET Core version of Nancy and even a sample. What did you add and how? Did you add the wrong NuGet package perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Sample project you shared is a web project        
 "<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">" , but my need to do this implementation in worker service . Just for information.. my project is "<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">" worker service not web.